# How do I print variable of object in collection in Java

Tags: java, object, collections

Particle particle;

```
ArrayList<Particle>list = new ArrayList<Particle>();
for (int x=0; 100 > x; x++ ){
    list.add(new Particle(1,1,"1"));
}


for (int z = 0; 100 > z ; z++){
    System.out.println(list.get(z));
}
```

and i would Like to get something like this

`System.out.println(list.get(z.variable) // which z is the particle ofc`

I would also like to know how do i refer to this particles in collection, I would like to **jump** on this particles changing their values.

Comment: Can you please write clearly what fields you Particle class has, and what do you want to print?

Comment: I feel your Particle class has constructor which should accept 3 arguments. Now you will save them to class variables of that class. If you want to print that object it will call the toString method. you have to override it as per required output.

Comment: public class Particle {

    int position =1;
    int value = 1;
    String image = "1";

    public Particle(int position, int value, String image ) {

    }
}
This is my Particle class ofc. thanks for advice, im now looking into "toString" and figuring it out, when im done ill probably ask some more questions ;)

Comment: The correct syntax to a access member variable `variable` of the particle at position `z` in the list `list`, if that's what you want to do,  is `list.get(z).variable`, and it will require that `variable` have `public` access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just want:

```
for (Particle p : list) {
    System.out.println(p.variable);
}
```

or with the C-style for statement:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < list.size() ; i++) {
    System.out.println(list.get(i).variable);
}
```

However, it's very atypical for a class to have public fields ("variables"), so I'm pretty sure you might have to access the variable with its getter, like so: `list.get(i).getVariable()`.

I'd suggest to read the source code of Particle.